# ATT authorization does not work on IOS 15

Tags: swift

I am using adjust to ask ATT Authorization, it works perfectly on ios 14 but not on ios 15.

I did it like this:

```
 if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        Adjust.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
            //you got permission to track
        })
    } else {
        //you got permission to track, iOS 14 is not yet installed
    }
```